# game in pygame but lots of functions with lots of parameters necessary to tidy up game loop

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game with Pygame in which the user can place machines that would output resources called producers and you can use those resources to craft items with crafters which you would then move the items to a seller with conveyors that's basically the main game. Since I would have a lot of sprites I can't do this

```
sprite1 = Producer()
sprite2= Producer()
```

To go around the I store the details of each sprite in a machine info dictionary containing its position, direction, item to output if producer, output quantity, and blueprint if crafter.

```
producer_info[decimal_co]=['n','copper',1]
new_producer=Producer(x,y)
producer_group.add(new_producer)
```

With that info if the user wants to rotate the sprite instead of using in built methods I check for changes in the machine_info dictionary and then change the image of sprite like this:

```
    def update(self):
        self.current_co=self.rect.topleft
        self.decimal_co=str(self.current_co[0])+'.'+str(self.current_co[1])
        #print(self.decimal_co,producer_info)

        if self.decimal_co not in producer_info.keys():
            self.kill()
        else:
            if producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='n':
                self.image=self.image_N
            elif producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='e':
                self.image=self.image_E
            elif producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='s':
                self.image=self.image_S
            elif producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='w':
                self.image=self.image_W
```

My main file was a bit messy especially the game loop so I decided to make some functions to use instead of all the code in the game loop but then I the main file became even messier with tons of functions and classes so I wanted to move the button functions to another file after doing so I realised that I needed to pass a lot of parameters.
Is there a problem with having too many parameters, it would make it a little unreadable but it makes sense to me. The purpose of these functions is to make the game loop easier to read and understand but if I remove any variables here then I would have to add code to the game loop.

Should I just carry on with lots of parameters and lots of functions or would it affect the performance of my game in any way as I don't mind if its unreadable and that the only issue with lots of parameters.

An example of a function that requires almost the max amount of parameters required out of all of my functions. Most functions would have a few less than this. This code will receive an array of selected positions of where the user wants to place the machines it will then check which machine the user chose to place earlier on and it will create an object of those machines and add another pair to my machine_info dictionary which stores info on all sprites of that machine type so they can be adjusted. This function is called when the user clicks some squares in the grid that they want to place machines in.

```
def place_machines(screen,grid_surface,selected_pos,selected_machine,producer_info,Producer,producer_group,crafter_info,Crafter,crafter_group,conveyor_info,Conveyor,conveyor_group,factory_layout):
    game_state='play'
    screen.blit(grid_surface,(0,100))
    for co in selected_pos:
        x= co[0]*40
        y= co[1]*40
        
        decimal_co=str(x)+'.'+str(y)
        str(decimal_co)
        print(decimal_co,'in function')
        if selected_machine =='producer':
            producer_info[decimal_co]=['n','copper',1]
            new_producer=Producer(x,y)
            producer_group.add(new_producer)
            factory_layout[co[0]][co[1]]=1
            have_producer=True
        elif selected_machine=='crafter':
            crafter_info[decimal_co]=['n','circuit',{}]
            new_crafter=Crafter(x,y)
            crafter_group.add(new_crafter)
            factory_layout[co[0]][co[1]]=1
            have_crafter=True
        elif selected_machine=='conveyor':
            conveyor_info[decimal_co]='n'
            new_conveyor=Conveyor(x,y)
            conveyor_group.add(new_conveyor)
            factory_layout[co[0]][co[1]]=1
            have_conveyor=True
            print(conveyor_info)
    selected_pos=[]
    return game_state
```

Comment: Your function is doing way too much while taking way too many arguments. Is this part of a class? What does the rest of your program look like? Please tell us more about your program and what the goal of the game is by editing the question.

Comment: (What is the expected effect of `selected_pos=[]` immediately before return?)

Comment: (`I don't mind if it's unreadable` see [Do I want the code to be good code?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using OOP.

Abstract class for `Machine` with its subclasses being `Producer`, `Crafter` and `Conveyor`. They store coordinates (as a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)), direction (as an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instance) and whatever other properties they are supposed to have (I wasn't able to fully decipher `['n','circuit',{}]`). Instance methods allow them to be `place`d, to `produce` resources etc.. While methods such as `produce()` are specific to concrete implementations (`Producer` in this case), `place()` is common among all the `Machine`s.

Which means instead of an if-else ladder you can use polymorphism:

```
if selected_machine =='producer':
    ...
elif selected_machine=='crafter':
    ...
elif selected_machine=='conveyor':
    ...
```

turns into

```
machine.place(pos)
```

Concrete `Machine`s can override the method with extra functionality if needed.

This is the main issue but there are a lot more to address:

`game_state='play'`
Game state should be an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instance. This way you can't assign an arbitrary value to it, it can have its own type, properties and methods.

`for co in selected_pos:`
What is `co`? I thought it might be a single coordinate, but then why are we accessing its elements next line and why is the method called `place_machines` and not `place_machine`? Names should convey the meaning of whatever they are naming.

`x= co[0]*40`
Why are we multiplying by 40? What is 40? Avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), make constants for them.

`decimal_co=str(x)+'.'+str(y)`
Instead of constructing and storing a string representation, you can use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) (which has a nice string representation built-in if you really need it).

`str(decimal_co)`
This line does nothing since `str` is a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

`producer_info[decimal_co]=['n','copper',1]`
As mentioned earlier, this `producer_info` becomes redundant if you use classes.

`factory_layout[co[0]][co[1]]=1`
This doesn't need to be a 2d dictionary, you can use the entire `co` as an index. Also, what is `1`? You can avoid using dictionaries and straight up storing occupied positions in a list.

`have_conveyor=True`
Avoid [global variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable), they are extremely error-prone.

```
if producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='n':
    self.image=self.image_N
elif producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='e':
    self.image=self.image_E
elif producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='s':
    self.image=self.image_S
elif producer_info[self.decimal_co][0]=='w':
    self.image=self.image_W
```

This can be shortened to one line by using an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) for directions.

Comment: in the shop there are a few machines the user can buy one when they click on it and whichever they do click on i need to remember that so i store it in the selected machines variable. the reason this variable is stored is because i need to allow the user to choose the positions they want to place the machines and then create the sprites in those locations.

Comment: selected pos is an array containing numerous co ordinates as arrays so it looks like this [[X1,Y1],[X2,Y2]]  so it would be for each co in the selected pos. however i have the grid surface which is an 800 by 800 image of a 20 by 20 grid so each machine would be 40 by 40 pixels. when the user clicks their mouse co is // by 40 to get which cell in the grid they have clicked no matter where in the cell and those co ordinates are sent into selected pos. the co ordinates are then checked against the factory layout 2d array which is a 20 by 20 array which has 0 for empty slots and 1 for full.

Comment: @AminAli my point is that those details should become clear after reading the code. It should be self-describing.

Comment: and i can only use the //40 cordinates to check in the factory layout but after that the co ordinates are *40 to get back to normal position of the topleft of the cell. i guess the function is called place machines instead of place machine because it places multiple machines. yes that str(decimal co ) is useless idk why its there.

Comment: i see yeh and i just wrote a crap ton explaining it which i shouldnt need to basically is what your saying

Comment: @AminAli basically. You can try fixing those mistakes and posting it in another question,

Comment: okay but about the machines class you were talking about i dont place any of my sprites with their methods and how would you rotate a sprite that doesnt have a set variable as sprite1=Machine()

Comment: as i cant think of any way to access the sprite if i dont have a set variable for it or a machine_info dictionary like i did.

Comment: @AminAli "i dont place any of my sprites with their methods" wdym?

Comment: the place machines is a function not a method of a class

Comment: the place_machines is called from within the game loop it just does some checks and then creates some sprites with given positions

Comment: @AminAli I don't see what you mean by "placing sprites with their methods".

Comment: perhaps i misunderstood what you were saying

Comment: i dont have a place_machines method i thought you assumed i did